# How to stop cocoapods from creating xcconfig file for each configuration

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a lot of configurations in addition to Debug and Release. However I only really want cocoapods to build with either Debug or Release. When I do `pod install` it creates .xcconfig files for each configuration even though they contain identical settings.

Is there a way to only create two files, and point the other configs to either one of those?

`Pods-TestSwiftGif.debug.xcconfig`

`Pods-TestSwiftGif.release.xcconfig`

[image]

Comment: did you manage to figure this out? would also like to know